# How to modify the entire screen display in Android, even outside the app

Tags: android

I'd like to create an Android app that can modify the whole display, even when the app is not being used directly. This is [one example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.lux) of an app that seems to do this.

Ideally, I'd not *only* want to be able to tint the screen, but to perform arbitrary operations on the pixels being shown on the display, ranging between making the entire screen a solid color, inverting the colors (so that e.g. black becomes white), and blurring the screen. (I could imagine this level of access in the wrong hands could make somebody's phone unusable, so maybe not all of these are possible.)

Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to let your app draw over other apps. There is a special set of requirements for such applications.

- Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY).
- There is also a simple [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/).
- And an opensource [app](https://github.com/LibreShift/red-moon), that looks pretty similar to one you've linked above.